# Nasm Assembly relational operators

Tags: assembly, nasm

I would like relational expressions like 1==1 to give 1 if true and 0 if false. Is there a simple way to do this in nasm assembly?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you give an example of how you would use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are reffering to x86 instruction set, then you probably need SETcc set of instructions: http://faydoc.tripod.com/cpu/setnz.htm

Answer (score 1):

The arithmetic operators provided by NASM are listed here, in increasing order of precedence: |, ^, &, << and >>, + and −, *, /, //, % and %%,+, −, ~, ! and SEG.
So there is no == operator in NASM.
You can compare two operands by using CMP instruction.